# MSQL error - #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

[I made this query with reference to this blog](https://blog.treasuredata.com/blog/2016/01/25/using-sql-and-r-to-do-funnel-analysis-part-1/)I am getting an error while using this query in MySQL.

The query logic is correct but I'm getting an error when running this in MySQL.

I looked at previous questions on StackOverflow, but didn't find something to help me.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
COUNT(Button) AS Button,
COUNT(BurgetMenu) AS BurgerMenu,
COUNT(Tabs) AS Tabs,
SUM(CASE WHEN Button <= BurgerMenu THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS conversion_1_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN Button <= BurgerMenu AND BurgerMenu <= Tabs THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
AS conversion_2_3

FROM (SELECT 
     user_id,
     MAX(CASE WHEN `event_type` = 'Button' THEN first_occurance ELSE NULL END) AS Button,
     MAX(CASE WHEN `event_type` = 'BurgerMenu' THEN first_occurance ELSE NULL END) AS BurgerMenu,
     MAX(CASE WHEN `event_type` = 'Tabs' THEN first_occurance ELSE NULL END)AS Tabs

  FROM (SELECT deviceid, `event_type`, `date_time` AS first_occurance
        FROM events
        WHERE `date_time` BETWEEN '2017-10-30' AND '2017-11-06'
           AND `event_type` IN('Button','BurgerMenu','Tabs')
           AND deviceid IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY `deviceid`, `event_type`) a

  GROUP BY `deviceid`)
```

I know that Stackoverflow has many answers for same error , but do please help with my query, i have referred with previous answers

Comment: `GROUP BY deviceid) as your_alias_here`

Comment: Thank you, it works